# smart table using pagination angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, smart-table

Using Angular smart table lib:

I just want to display the pagination buttons on the bottom.  According to the documentation, it looks like st-pagination directives inserts those dom elements in there.  However, for me, it is not working.  Here is the plunker given by the smart table documentation:http://plnkr.co/edit/wzUHcc9PBF6tzH8iAEsn?p=preview

Here is my table footer code:

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
      <div st-items-by-page="10" st-pagination="">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

I must be misunderstanding something.  I know you can put your own customized template for the pagination.

Here is a screenshot, of the output and debugger:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a JSfiddle or Plunker to show the problem you have?

Comment: @leo.fcx - Sorry, its quite a big of an application.  I threw in a screenshot with a debugger to show whats going on.

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 1 page of data?

Comment: @SteamDev - Yes, I have 23 rows and st-items-by-page attribute is set to 10.

Comment: How many columns are there in the <tbody> ? <tfoot> colspan="5" . But <tbody> can be column more than <tfoot>

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<td>` tag only. you should not use `<div>` tag.

OK

```
<td colspan="5" class="text-center" st-items-by-page="10" st-pagination="">
</td>
```

NG

```
<td colspan="5" class="text-center">
  <div st-items-by-page="10" st-pagination="">
  </div>
</td>
```